# Persimmon tree - leaves turning black

Tags: fruit-trees

[image: three months old persimmon tree]

[image]

I planted this persimmon tree on March 2019. We are in Texas. The tree was growing very well in the first month, I begun to notice there is something wrong with leaves. The leaves are falling. Three weeks ago, I started to spray diluted neem oil (one tablespoon neem oil in half gallon water). The leaves still did not look healthy.

This picture was taken on March 29th, 20 days after I planted the football. The tree was happy and healthy

[image]

The following picture showed the disease on the tee leaves.

[image]

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vC9k.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "Persimmon/Kaki"? Could you make a photo on the bottom side of leaves? Did you use neem oil also on the bottom side of the leaves?

Comment: When you say you planted the tree, you do mean putting the rootball into the ground, in other words, its not in a  pot in the ground is it?  Can I ask what all the white material is  arouind the ouitside of the tree on the ground? Have you kept  it well watered since planting it?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I added the couple more pictures to the question. The white materials are the rocks. This tree is permission fuyu.  I did try to spray need oil on both side of the leaves. I planted the rootball into the ground three weeks ago. In the first couple weeks, I watered twice a week. In the first month, the tree was happy and healthy, it grew very well. The sign of disease showed up after 4 or 5 weeks, one branch almost lost all the leaves.

Comment: I've never grown persimmons, but I would suspect mites of some kind. Weaker plants can be more susceptible (so there could be a nutrient problem).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Fuyu. Look at this site: http://era.daf.qld.gov.au/id/eprint/2210/11/Problem_solver-persimmon.pdf
It says it's a calcium deficiency and it advises you to use lime, dolomite or gypsum
according to your soil analysis.
One problem, though: I have 4 of them, and only one has the problem. It had it while still in the pot. I am treating it, but I don't know the outcome yet.